# Writing subprocess stdout to a file truncates to 4096 bytes

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, python-3.8

I am trying to to write stdout to a file for something running in subprocess. My problem is that I the output is always truncated to 4096 bytes (one page size) which I believe is due to the PIPE size on a x86 system?

I set up my subprocess like this

```
with open("newfile.txt", "w") as f:
    proc = subprocess.Popen([find_executable(bin_name), *extra_args],
                             stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Let it run while doing other things, then

```
def shutdown(process):
    if process.poll() is None:
        try:
            process.terminate()
            process.wait(timeout.PROCESS_QUIT)
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            print(f"Process {process.args} not terminating after {timeout.PROCESS_QUIT} sec.",
                  file=sys.stderr)
            process.kill()
```

The output in newfile.txt always prints up to exactly 4096 bytes then truncates (usually mid line)

I've tried adding context.file_to_close.flush() periodically but this doesn't seem to have any impact one way or the other. How can I make the entirety of stdout be printed to a file?

strace gives me 7000+ lines of output, I'm not super sure how to read it but this seems to be everything related to the newfile.txt?

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "newfile.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
ioctl(6, TCGETS, 0x7ffc05c3fac0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(6, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
ioctl(6, TCGETS, 0x7ffc05c3f9c0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(6, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
stat("/basepath/project/build-behave/the_app.app", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=5355744, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
pipe2([8, 9], O_CLOEXEC)                = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fb12fc44a10) = 1349
close(9)                                = 0
close(7)                                = 0
read(8, "", 50000)                      = 0
close(8)                                = 0
close(6)                                = 0
```

(Edited code per mata and Charles Duffy's suggestions)

Comment: It should have nothing to do with the pipe size. The file handle is passed to the started process directly, and written there. There should be no need to flush it in the parent process. What else are you doing with the file in the parent?

Comment: Nothing else. I open the file, feed it to the subprocess when I Popen, store the file handle in the behave test context, then close it after I terminate the subprocess

Comment: I assumed a pipe size issue because I originally had stdout writing to subprocess.PIPE and that also caped at 4096 due to this issue https://bugs.python.org/issue41586. Writing to a file is my attempt to bypass this limit

Comment: Is the process writing a lot to stderr, and are your reading it? If you're not consuming it while the process is running, your problem might be that the process blocks on writing to THAT pipe. If you don't read it, send it to subprocess.DEVNULL instead. And there seems to be no reason to keep the file open in the context, you should just close it immediately after starting the subprocess (it won't be closed there).

Comment: Ah okay, good to know, thank you! I redirected my stderr to subprocess.DEVNULL and also immediately closed the file after popen. newfile.txt still seems to be truncating at the same point though

Comment: `strace` or another syscall-level tracing tool (I personally use and recommend sysdig) is the right place to reach here. The prior comments indicating that the child is inheriting a direct handle on the file, not a pipe, are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I probably just don't know how to interpret `strace ` output but I'm having trouble finding where it actually writes anything to the file. I found the location here it opens and then closes the file and some `ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device) ` errors in between but no writes?

Answer (score 2):

There are no pipes here; `Popen` only creates them if you pass it `subprocess.PIPE`.

Most programming languages have a standard library that buffers output to files, to reduce the number of system calls (which are expensive). 4096 bytes is a common default size for the buffer.

If the process exits normally, any data remaining in the buffer is flushed to the file.

You are calling `terminate` on the process. On Windows, this calls `TerminateProcess`, which immediately kills the process with no warning. On Unix-likes, it sends `SIGTERM`, which can be handled by flushing buffers, etc., but just because it can be handled doesn't mean it will be.

You need to either fix the problem that is preventing the process from exiting, and then wait unconditionally for it to exit on its own, or else signal to it to flush its buffers in a way that it will understand. The way you'd do either of those things depends on what process you're running.

> I've tried adding context.file_to_close.flush()

Assuming `context.file_to_close` is the same as `f`, this won't do anything, because it flushes the buffer in the Python process, not the buffer in the subprocess.

(Incidentally, you probably don't need to save `f` and close it later. You can probably close it as soon as `Popen` returns, because the subprocess has its own handle to the file at that point.)

From a comment:

> Is the process writing a lot to stderr, and are your reading it? If you're not consuming it while the process is running, your problem might be that the process blocks on writing to THAT pipe. If you don't read it, send it to subprocess.DEVNULL instead.

This can indeed prevent the process from exiting, if you pass `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` (as you did in the first version of the question).

But replacing it with `stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL` means you won't see any error messages the subprocess is printing. There may be a message explaining why it isn't exiting.

It's probably best to omit the `stderr` argument entirely, so that the subprocess inherits your `stderr`, at least for testing.

Comment: Thanks benrg! You say "signal to it to flush its buffers in a way that it will understand" and that  " context.file_to_close ... won't do anything, because it flushes the buffer in the Python process, not the buffer in the subprocess". So then what is the correct way to signal for the subprocess to flush its output to the file?

Comment: @Indigo It depends on what the subprocess is. There may be no way to do it. On Windows you could try `send_signal(CTRL_C_EVENT)` (see the `subprocess` docs for details), but I wouldn't be surprised if that didn't work. The best bet is to figure out why the subprocess isn't exiting normally.